# ExtJS 4: Saving record in record edit form to server and update grid store

Tags: .net, extjs, proxy, save, asmx

Below, I have a grid of project records.  I'm loading the project record list via an asmx web service.  I'm returning a List object in .NET via a json proxy to my project list store.  Each Project object binds to my Project model.  Double clicking a row in the project list grid launches the Project Edit form.

I'm struggling with saving an edit to a record in my popup form (widget.projectedit) after clicking the "Save" button.  I'm not sure whether I should be sending my update to the project store and syncing my store with my proxy, or setting up a separate store and proxy for a single Project record, and then just refresh my project store and view.

"editProject" is being called to launch my form.  I want "updateProject" to update my record, but I don't have a delegate for it yet (I'm not invoking/calling it in the code below).

**Specific questions:**

*How do I call the "updateProject" function?*

*How do I update my project list grid store?*

*What code changes do I need?  (I can figure out what code to put in the asmx service.. I just need help with the JavaScript code)*

[image]

**ProjectList.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProjectList.ascx.cs" Inherits="Web.Controls.ProjectList.ProjectList" %>

<div id="example-grid"></div>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="PageScriptManager" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/WebService1.asmx" InlineScript="false" />
    </Services>
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/ext-4/ext-all-debug.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Controls/ProjectList/ProjectList.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Controls/ProjectList/Proxy.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.panel.*',
    'Ext.layout.container.Border'
]);

    Ext.namespace('EXT');

    Ext.define('Project', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
        'project_id',
        'project_name',
        'project_number'
    ]
    });

    Ext.define('ProjectEdit', {
        extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
        alias: 'widget.projectedit',

        title: 'Edit Project',
        layout: 'fit',
        autoShow: true,

        initComponent: function () {
            this.items = [
                {
                    xtype: 'form',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'project_id',
                            fieldLabel: 'Project ID'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'project_number',
                            fieldLabel: 'Project Number'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'textfield',
                            name: 'project_name',
                            fieldLabel: 'Project Name'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];

            this.buttons = [
                {
                    text: 'Save',
                    action: 'save'
                },
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    scope: this,
                    handler: this.close
                }
            ];

            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });

    var store = new Ext.data.Store(
{
    proxy: new Ext.ux.AspWebAjaxProxy({
        url: 'http://localhost/WebService1.asmx/GetProjects',
        actionMethods: {
            create: 'POST',
            destroy: 'DELETE',
            read: 'POST',
            update: 'POST'
        },
        extraParams: {
            myTest: 'a',
            bar: 'foo'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            model: 'Project',
            root: 'd'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
        }
    })
});

    Ext.define('ProjectGrid', {
        extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

        initComponent: function () {
            var me = this;

            Ext.applyIf(me, {
                store: store,
                columns: [
                    { text: 'Project ID', width: 180, dataIndex: 'project_id', sortable: true },
                    { text: 'Project Number', width: 180, dataIndex: 'project_number', sortable: true },
                    { text: 'Project Name', width: 180, dataIndex: 'project_name', sortable: true }
                ],
                listeners: {
                    itemdblclick: this.editProject
                }
            });

            me.callParent(arguments);
        },

        editProject: function (grid, record) {
            var view = Ext.widget('projectedit');
            view.down('form').loadRecord(record);
        },

        updateProject: function (button) {
            var win = button.up('window'),
            form = win.down('form'),
            record = form.getRecord(),
            values = form.getValues();

            record.set(values);
            win.close();
            // synchronize the store after editing the record
            this.getProjectStore().sync();
        }
    });

    // create the grid
    var grid = Ext.create('ProjectGrid', {
        title: 'Project List',
        renderTo: 'example-grid',
        width: 540,
        height: 200
    });

    store.load();

</script>
```

**Web Service:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Xml;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Web
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public class Project
        {
            public string project_id;
            public string project_number;
            public string project_name;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json,
            UseHttpGet = false, XmlSerializeString = false)]
        public List<Project> GetProjects(string myTest, string bar)
        {
            var list = new List<Project>(new[] {
                new Project() {project_id="1", project_name="project 1", project_number="001"},
                new Project() {project_id="2", project_name= "project 2", project_number= "002" },
                new Project() {project_id="3", project_name= "project 3", project_number= "003" }
            });

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to decide:

ONE: load and save a model in the editor window independently.

sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/el_chief/rUaV3/4/

(above ajax saving is fake, so you won't see update on the grid).

TWO: pass in the model from the caller, and save the model in the caller.

sample code: http://jsfiddle.net/el_chief/5jjBS/4/

ONE is a bit slower, but everything is independent and you can test them independently too.-

Also, if you pass in the model from the caller and the user makes changes and then closes the child window, those changes MAY appear in the caller (depending how you do your view/model syncing).

Also, oftentimes, you will want to only grab a few fields to display on grids, but show all the fields on an item-view form. In which case, you need option ONE.

Either way, you should pass in a callback function to the child window, that it calls when it is "done". This way you can get back any data needed from the child window, and close it if need be.

You don't need a singular store for the window either. You should put your proxies on your models (the store uses its models proxy and you can always override it)

One key aspect to saving is that you need to return some data, usually a full record like:

```
{
success:true,
contacts:[
{
id:1,
name:'neil mcguigan updated record'
}
]
}
```

Comment: Hi Neil.  This is great info.  However, I'm wondering if you'd be able to share a full example with me to get me started?  I've posted several questions in the last week or so for my different tests (MVC, ASP.NET and ASMX, ASP.NET and WCF, etc..) and attempting to get all CRUD operations working for a single model.  Would you be willing to share your code?  Right now, I have the load working, and a save almost working (with the Ext.ajax.request call), which I think is what #2 is doing, right?

Comment: Ok, but you have to promise to do something nice for a stranger :) Code en route...